# Is there any option to run parametrized setup_function?

Tags: python, pytest

I wrought some tests and now i have a problem with them. that test are parametrized:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    ...
    metafunc.parametrized("param", range(1,2,3)

def test_sometest(param):
    ...
```

and now i want to write a setup_function function, that would know about the parametr. something like that:

```
def setup_function(function, param):
    ...
```

so is there any option to make this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a fixture instead of `setup_function()`:

```
import pytest

pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
def fix(request):
    if request.param == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def test_sometest(fix):
    pass
```

This is also better then the `pytest_generate_tests` method because py.test can determine which tests will be executed before it actually needs to start executing tests, which helps with selection of tests to run (`-k`) etc.